# maven dependency:analyze fails to build GWT module

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-dependency-plugin

Given multi-module project, I need to find out all unused dependencies.
I tried to use maven-dependency-plugin and it's target 'dependency:analyze', however it fails to compile my GWT module.

It seems that having any generator in GWT descriptor is not resolved if dependency plugin is enabled.

```
<generate-with class="project.rebind.ToolBinderGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable
            class="project.client.command.ToolBinder"/>
</generate-with>
```

standalone Maven build works just fine.

Comment: What's the compilation error you're seeing?

Comment: ClassNotFound for ToolBinder

Comment: All others generators, the one from GWT SDK, are recognized?